# how to access and change char array in c x86 AT&T inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I'm having trouble solving a school exercise , I'm supposed to change a char array in c using inline assembly. In this case change "ahoy" to "aXoy", but I'm getting segmentation fault. This is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        char string[] = "ahoy";
        __asm__ volatile (
                "mov %0, %%eax;"
                "movb $'X', 1(%%eax);"
                : "=m"(string) : "0"(string) : "memory", "eax");
        printf("%s\n", string);
        return 0
    }
```

with this: `"mov %0, %%eax;"` I'm trying to store address of the array in register

then with this: `"movb $'X', 1(%%eax);"` I want to store byte 'X' in location pointed to by (%%eax) offset by 1 byte(char),

I have string both as output and input, and "memory","eax" in clobber since I'm modifying both. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: If you want to use `string` as input AND output then mark it as `"+m"` instead of `"=m"`and then drop the `"0"(string)` altogether. This line `mov %0, %%eax;` will move the 32-bit value AT the memory address to _EAX_ since %0 is a memory operand. You want to put the ADDRESS of %0 in _EAX_ it appears. Use `lea %0, %%eax;` instead of `mov %0, %%eax;`

Comment: Secondly: Are you compiling this as 64-bit or 32-bit code? The inline assembly as is using a 32-bit register with a stack based address (`string`) will fault since the stack address can't be represented properly in a 32-bit value. Make sure you compile this with `-m32` or modify the code to use a 64-bit register for the address (RAX instead of EAX)

Comment: `__asm__ volatile (
                "lea %0, %%eax;"
                "movb $'X', 1(%%eax);"
                : "+m"(string) :: "memory", "eax");`

Comment: hmm I read somewhere that the + suffix doesn't work in inline gcc assembly, nvm gonna try it

Comment: The `+` modifier has been around for almost forever. They are all documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers

Comment: alright, it works wow, one of my other problems actually was that I didn't have some of the c libraries installed for some reason, <bits/libc-header-start.h> to be precise

Comment: @MIchael Petch thank you very much

Comment: Technically speaking in this case using `+m` you don't need to use the `memory` clobber since  the compiler will realize all of the `string` in memory first since you are using an `m` constraint. Alternatively you could have done `__asm__ volatile (
                "movb $'X', 1(%0);"
                :: "r"(string) : "memory");` . Memory clobber would be needed since in this case you are passing the address of `string` through a register and not a memory operand.

Comment: Not sure why with the code shown you'd need `<bits/libc-header-start.h>`

Comment: well maybe it's an unrelated issue, but this file didn't compile successfully until I downloaded gcc-multilib package for ubuntu

Comment: You wouldn't need to include `<bits/libc-header-start.h>` directly but one of the includes you use may need it - yes. And to compile 32-bit on 64-bit with Ubuntu you do need multilib support if you use the _C_ library(it usually causes a bunch of linker errors if you don't). `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` usually solves that but I gather you are saying you figured that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gcc -S` instead of `-c` to look at the compiler's assembly output and you should see what's wrong. The `"m"` constraint produces a memory reference expression for accessing the object associated with it, not a register containing its address. So it will expand to something like `(%ecx)`, not `%ecx`, and the first `mov` will load 4 bytes from `string`, rather than the address of `string`, into `eax`.

One way to fix this would be to use a register constraint `"r"(string)` instead.

Alternatively you could replace the `mov` with `lea`: `lea %0, %%eax`.

There are other issues with your code too like the useless temporary/clobber register `eax` but they shouldn't keep it from working.

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding this... so effectively you're saying the only thing I have to change is : "=m"(string) to : "=r"(string)? because in that case compiler tells me there is an 'impossible constraint in 'asm''

Comment: Sorry, if you use `"r"` it needs to be just an input, and you need a memory clobber (which you already have). That's because the expression `string` is not a modifiable lvalue; it's now being used in a context where it decays to a pointer.